# Word for person who looks for flattery

Tags: interpersonal-relations

What word could be used to describe a person who seeks and seems to depend on constant positive feedback from the people around him.

Answer (score 2):

Not a single word but a common idiom is to say someone is "***[fishing for compliments](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fish+for+compliments)***".

> Alice: I really hate the fit of this dress
>   Jane: Oh, you look great - stop fishing for compliments.